# how to call a function from alert in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
alert("Your ID is"+randomString());



if ($('#txtAgree').is(':checked')) {
        alert("You have succesfully submitted the form Thank You:");
        var params = $("#payuForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin/api/process_pay.php",
            data: params,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                //alert("yes");
                alert("Your ID is"+randomString());
                refreshAdd();

            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please Select terms and conditions:");
        return false;
    }




    // return true;
} catch (ex) {
    alert("Error -> : " + ex.message);
}
});




function randomString() {
var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var string_length = 8;
var randomstring = '';
for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
}
document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
}
```

Here I am a calling javascript function through the alert.
  I want unique key each form submission and form get executed through ajax call. The above is My code.
Here I am a calling javascript function through the alert.
  I want unique key each form submission and form get executed through ajax call. The above is My code.

Comment: add more details and code

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your method of calling a function within alert(). Return value as string will be concatenated to "Your ID is". Just add a space after "is"

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: The alert is not Executing.

Comment: showing this error    Cannot read property 'randomfield' of undefined

Comment: Copy my function for randomstring instead of yours. See answer below

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer.

Comment: One more question how to save this id into database.

Comment: Thats kind of a new question. Check this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function randomString() {
var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var string_length = 8;
var randomstring = '';
for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
}

return randomstring; //was missing in your code
}
```

You didn't return randomstring from your function